# Cannot search through the ListView, returns zero results

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using a ListView with custom Adapter and I have a EditText for searching through the List.
When I type anything in the EditText it empties with ListView.
Note: I am displaying ListView in a Dialog which is in a Fragment

I have added TextChangedListener as well.
Not sure where I am going wrong.
please suggest.

```
CompanyAdapter companyAdapter;

private void showCompaniesDialog(List<Company> companies) {
        if(companies != null) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
            // dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_company_listview);

            Button btndialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btndialog);
            btndialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listview);
            companyAdapter = new CompanyAdapter(getActivity(), 0, companies);
            listView.setAdapter(companyAdapter);

            //HERE I SET THE TEXT FILTER ENABLED
            listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //textView.setText("You have clicked : " + companies[position]);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            //HERE I ADD CHANGED LISTENER
            EditText etSearch = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
            etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    companyAdapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    //companyAdapter.getFilter().filter(editable);
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }

    }
```

Company Adapter

```
    public class CompanyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Company>{
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CompanyAdapter (Activity activity, int textViewResourceId, List<Company> lCompany){
        super(activity, textViewResourceId, lCompany);
        try{
            this.activity = activity;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Company getItem (Company position){
        return position;
    }

    public  long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    public  class ViewHolder {
        public TextView display_name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.company_list_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.display_name = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvCompanyName);


                vi.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }
            holder.display_name.setText(getItem(position).getName());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return vi;
    }

}
```

Company class for name field

```
@SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

 public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Comment: I don;t see you have implemented the filterring. It won't magically understand how exactly you want to filter it

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko As Ganesh Suggested I have implemented the ItemFilter, and I can see the results passed to publishResults method, but notifyDataSetChanged does not work, List is not updated with  the new results. any suggestions on what I might be missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapter must `implements Filterable`, Check this Example

```
public class SearchableAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private List<String>originalData = null;
    private List<String>filteredData = null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();

    public SearchableAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.filteredData = data ;
        this.originalData = data ;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return filteredData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filteredData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // A ViewHolder keeps references to children views to avoid unnecessary calls
        // to findViewById() on each row.
        ViewHolder holder;

        // When convertView is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
        // to reinflate it. We only inflate a new View when the convertView supplied
        // by ListView is null.
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
            // we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

            // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        // If weren't re-ordering this you could rely on what you set last time
        holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final List<String> list = originalData;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<String> nlist = new ArrayList<String>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                filterableString = list.get(i);
                if (filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                    nlist.add(filterableString);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredData = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
}

//in your Activity or Fragment where of Adapter is instantiated :

editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        System.out.println("Text ["+s+"]");

        mSearchableAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());                           
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh, the list I am passing is not just string, they are objects, how can ItemFilter does not work in that case. any other example where ItemFilter uses List<Object> instead of List<String>

Comment: I will modify it accordingly and try

Comment: Hi @Ganesh Pokale , I have implemented the way you said, and in the ItemFilter it is filtering through the data and returning `results` to piublishResults, but I think notifyDataSetChanged() does not work. Though the data is filtered in the ItemFilter, data is not updated in the List

Comment: On PublishResults function before notifyDataSetChanged(), the filteredData has the right data which should be displayed, but the list is not refreshed.

Comment: Did you check all usage of filteredData list in my adapter Like in                
  public int getCount() {
        return filteredData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filteredData.get(position);
    }

Comment: Also  in getview holder.text.setText(filteredData.get(position));